# Increasing TCP/IP Window size

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to send messages over tcp/ip between two servers.
I want to send a message that is 30KB.
But I want to send it with as a whole.
I don't want tcp protocol to break it into segments.

I am using communication between 2 Windows Server 2008 R2.
The client and the server are coded using c#.
I tryed using

```
tcpclnt.SendBufferSize = 100000;
tcpclnt.Client.DontFragment = true;
```

and the same at the server.

I also tried configuring the window size of the server(editing the registry).

Comment: He doesn't want TCP to break his data into segments. So, the question is how can he avoid fragmentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altering buffersize will have the sideeffect of ramping up ram usage - not recommended...

As TCP actually deals with streams and not packets (UDP uses packets), I believe your answer lies within framing the message, see [message framing](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/message-framing.html)

see also [code](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html)

Found this possible solution somewhat later but thought it should be included here:

[SetTcpWindowSize](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/networking/client/#SetTcpWindowSize.htm)

Search towards the bottom for a VB example entitled "Setting the TCP Window Size for All Network Adapters"

Alternatively there is a buffer handler here which looks like it will do the job of allowing you to read a message in one part even if it is in multiple packets it will allow you to reassemble them via buffer management. See [this link](http://www.lfsforum.net/showthread.php?t=41210)

Comment: Ok, But if I do want to change it?

Comment: have a look at the link called code above, this is one implementation... the developer has basically ripped off http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/ which I would recommend investigating. Read http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37496/TCP-IP-Protocol-Design-Message-Framing for more good info

Comment: Another good reason not to fiddle with the window size is explained here http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPWindowSizeAdjustmentandFlowControl.htm i.e. window size in TCP is used as a vital flow control mechanism.

Comment: Also if you do fiddle with the flow control mechanism beware http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silly_window_syndrome

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly suggest that you need to carry out further research into [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header) and [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure), as well as [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Structure) and [Gigabit Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet#Varieties) (particularly [Jumbo Frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame)).

Essentially, the short answer to your question is that you cannot send a single IP datagram containing a TCP payload of 30kb, despite the IP header permitting a maximum size of 64kb for the complete datagram.

The reason for this is that the underlying network (most likely Ethernet or Gigabit Ethernet) will have smaller frame sizes, and will therefore require the IP datagram to be fragmented in order to transmit that datagram over the physical network within the frame size limitations of that network.

The TCP protocol does guarantee successful delivery of a complete, uncorrupted datagram (via automatic reassembly, automatic detection of corrupted datagrams and automatic retransmissions of lost or corrupted datagrams), so unless you have a highly specialised requirement, you should be able to just let the TCP stack fragment your message and reassemble it on your behalf.